ValueError: Can't determine UID type for private UIDs
In the handle_store() method, while reading event dataset. I get the error - ValueError: Can't determine UID type for private UIDs.
Stacktrace:
File "/dicom_cmove_scp.py", line 203, in handle_store
    ds = event.dataset
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pynetdicom/events.py", line 621, in dataset
    return self._get_dataset("DataSet", msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pynetdicom/events.py", line 823, in _get_dataset
    t_syntax.is_implicit_VR,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydicom/uid.py", line 99, in is_implicit_VR
    if self.is_transfer_syntax:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pydicom/uid.py", line 134, in is_transfer_syntax
    raise ValueError("Can't determine UID type for private UIDs.")
ValueError: Can't determine UID type for private UIDs.

Why is this issue caused? Is there a way to store the file without reading UIDs and store it for investigation purposes?

To store the file you need the transfer syntax it is encoded in. The error happens while determining the transfer syntax (probably a private transfer syntax?). I suggest you add an issue/question directly in pynetdicom.

Where exactly do I ask this question?

Best create a dissussion issue in pynetdicom.
